# Using bootstrap typeahead

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, expressionengine

I've been trying to get bootstrap typeahead to work, however been having some difficulties doing so.

My code is the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var subjects = [{exp:freeform:entries form_id="2" status="open|closed|pending"}"<?php echo mb_strtolower('{freeform:field:school_name}', 'UTF-8'); ?>", {/exp:freeform:entries}];
    $('input.typeahead"]').typeahead({source: subjects});
});
</script>

<h2>Έχει κάνει ήδη στο σχολείο σας αίτηση;</h2>
<p>Κοιτάξτε τη λίστα πιο κάτο</p>   
{exp:freeform:entries form_id="2" status="open|closed|pending" limit="1"}
    <input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="    {freeform:absolute_results}" class="typeahead">
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

The exp tags you see are expression engine queries.

var subjects is an array populated by an expression engine query. this is the output as it comes out of the query.

```
["δημοτικο σχολειο κοκκινοτριμιθιασ α΄", "δημοτικο σχολειο γερμασογειασ", " δημοτικό σχολείο α&#39; καϊμακλίου", "στ΄ δημοτικό σχολείο αγλαντζιάς", "δημοτικό σχολείο αγίου βασιλείου (κ.β.)", "γ&#39; δημοτικό σχολείο λεμεσού", "β&#39; δημοτικό καϊμακλίου", "τεχνικη σχολη μακαριοσ γ&#39;", "gymnasio agiou vasiliou ", "β δημοτικο σχολειο αγλαντζιασ", "α δημοτικο σχολειο αγλατνζιασ", "δημοτικό σχολείο κακοπετριας", "δημοτικό σχολείο αγίου ανδρέα ", "ενιαίο ολοήμερο περιφερειακό δημοτικό σχολείο κυπερούντας", "δημοτικό σχολείο δευτεράς", "ενιαίο ολοήμερο δημοτικό τριμήκληνης", "δημοτικό σχολείο επισκοπής", "β΄ δημοτικό σχολείο ύψωνα", "ενιαίο ολοήμερο δημοτικό ερήμης", "b&#39; ποταμού γερμασόγειας  ", "α΄ δημοτικο σχολειο δαλιου", "ενιαίο ολοήμερο περιφερειακό δημοτικό σχολείο &quot;ιαματική&quot;", "τεχνική και γεωργική σχολή αμμοχώστου αυγόρου", "περιφερειακο δημοτικο σχολειο καλου χωριου λεμεσου", "δημοτικό αγίων ομολογητών", "δημοτικο σχολειο καμπιων", "ιβ΄ λανίτειο δημοτικό λεμεσού (κβ)", "ενιαιο ολοημερο δημοτικο σχολειο αψιουσ", "δημοτικό σχολείο ακρωτηρίου", "iz&#39; δημοτικό λεμεσού", "δημοτικό σχολείο πισσουρίου", "kστ΄ δημοτικό λ/σού-παναγίας τριχερούσας", "κη δημοτικό λεμεσού", "δημοτικο λιβαδιων κ.β.", "β΄ δημοτικό λεμεσού κ.β΄", "δημοτικό σχολείο μαμμάρων", "δημοτικό σχολείο λυμπιών", "α&#39; δημοτικό σχολείο αραδίππου", "δημοτιο σχολειο κυβιδων", "δημοτικο αγιου μαρωνα", "β&#39; δημοτικο σχολειο ξυλοφαγου", "α&#39; δημοτικό σχολείο ύψωνα", "γυμνάσιο τραχωνίου ", "the american academy nicosia", "pascal english school/ ελληνική σχολή πασκαλ", "pascal english school/ ελληνική σχολή πασκαλ", "περιφερειακο λυκειο αποστολου λουκα κολοσσιου", ];
```

Now when I run the code, I get a message in the console, saying "uncaught referencerror: $ is not defined"

My first thought was that bootstrap did not contain the js plugin, however on double checking the boostrap git.io site, it clearly states that it is packaged in there. I even ran a ctrl+f on the js file and found references to the function (downloaded from http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/).

Anyone got any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok silly mistake, the page was to be loaded thru an ajax request. When testing the call, I ran the script file it's self that didnt include my header and thus links to css & js files. doh!